# How did my default file permissions get changed from 666 (before umask settings) to 04501

Tags: centos

I have an installation of CentOS 6.5 that suddenly started having issues with dealing out file permissions on new or recreated files.  when I create a file with touch, instead of the usual 644 or -rw-r--r-- I am seeing -r-s-----x as the permissions assigned to the new file.  I am logged in as root and I am attempting this file creation in my personal /home/myusername directory.

When I run an strace against touch, using the command 'strace touch filename 2>&1 | grep filename', I see this..

open("filename", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 04501) = 3
The 04501 is usually where we would see the 666, the default permissions for files prior to umask settings being applied (my umask is 0022)

I have ran AVG against this box, ran rkhunter, Googled for days, and I'm out of ideas.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: oops.. the strace output should read open("filename"..etc..etc..04501)=3  my bad

Comment: Don't comment, just [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Looks like very bad news. GNU coreutils `touch` contains this code:

```
      int default_permissions =
        S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;
      fd = fd_reopen (STDIN_FILENO, file,
                      O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK | O_NOCTTY,
                      default_permissions);
```

which suggests that it always creates files with the exact same permissions, and `default_permissions` always has the value `0666` (which is expressed with symbolic constants in the source code).

It looks like your copy of `touch` has been tampered with. It is especially suspicious that the permissions it is now using have the set-user-id bit set.

Comment: I thought of that.  I brought in a new copy of touch from a known good server, and it continued this same behavior.

Comment: Then it could be a library that `touch` is using, most likely `libc6`.

Comment: Can someone compare this file size and last modified date to their known good Centos6.5 installation? [root@libun1 lib]# ls -al |grep libstd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    262024 Nov 10  2010 libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        31 Oct 30 14:19 libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 -> libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so

Comment: We thought we reinstalled all the c libraries yesterday before I posted this question, but we may have missed something.  The odd thing is that this file only exists on this Centos 6.5 box, not on the other two I have.

Comment: Also, cp gives the wrong file permissions.  Here's an strace.  [root@libun1 proefrockj]# strace cp jason jason2 2>&1 |grep jason
execve("/bin/cp", ["cp", "jason", "jason2"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
stat("jason2", 0x7fffd96f7e90)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("jason", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("jason2", 0x7fffd96f7cb0)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("jason", O_RDONLY)                 = 3
open("jason2", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0301) = 4

Comment: That last "0301" is "0666" on a known good server.

Comment: This is also independent of user, as I get the same result as root as I do as a standard user.

Comment: I also found that tar is not affected by this permissions issue.  Even when "tarring up" files that have the incorrect permissions, the .tar file is created with the usual 644 permissions.  Interesting.